# Scala akka actor system - RuntimeException when loading extension

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I am new with scala and I face the following problem.

```
import akka.actor.Actor
import akka.actor.Props
import akka.event.Logging
import akka.actor.ActorSystem


object test extends App {

  val system = ActorSystem("hello-world")
  val myActor = system.actorOf(Props[MyActor], "myactor2")
}
class MyActor extends Actor {
  val log = Logging(context.system, this)
  val props1 = Props[MyActor]
  def receive = {
       case "test" => log.info("received test")
       case _      => log.info("received unknown message")
  }
  val child = context.actorOf(Props[MyActor], name = "myChild")
}
```

So when I run it, I receive

```
[error] (run-main-1) java.lang.RuntimeException: While trying to load extension [akka.actor.InstanceCountingExtension]
java.lang.RuntimeException: While trying to load extension [akka.actor.InstanceCountingExtension]
        at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.$anonfun$loadExtensions$1(ActorSystem.scala:906)
        at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:929)
        at scala.collection.Iterator.foreach$(Iterator.scala:929)
        at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1406)
        at scala.collection.IterableLike.foreach(IterableLike.scala:71)
        ...
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: akka.actor.InstanceCountingExtension
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:530)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
[trace] Stack trace suppressed: run last compile:run for the full output.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit code: 1
        at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
```

The problem is the ActorSystem, but i can't understand why. When I delete the system an `myActor` everything works fine. It even works when i make it only  `val system = ActorSystem` but then system couldn't create `actorOf`.

Comment: Could you give us the version for your akka dependencies?

Answer (score 1):

You probably have this setting in your `application.conf`

```
akka.library-extensions += "akka.actor.InstanceCountingExtension"
```

This is an actor system extension used by `akka-actor-tests` to make assertions about the number of actor instances currently running in a system.

I don't think this is intended as an extension to be used by applications, it is more like a test utility.

However, depending on what you need:

1. if you just want to run your program, just delete the configuration line above, and all should be fine
2. if you need the extension for some reason, import `akka-actor-tests` test jar, or alternatively make sure you got [this class](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor-tests/src/test/scala/akka/actor/ExtensionSpec.scala#L33) available at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the test folder. When I removed the test it started working.